# Google Drive access the files and folder present

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I wanna create an Android activity which displays the file structure of the user's GoogleDrive account. In simple words, when user clicks on a Button, say, **Files in Google Drive**, the user should be directed to the GoogleDrive Homepage i.e. the page where the files and folder are displayed. The user can access the files, create new files, delete existing files, etc. I am using the code present [here](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) to complete this project. I need help create this activity.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @DaImTo Hey, thanks. You think you can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [GDAA](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) (the demo you mention) since it only supports FILE scope. That means it will only see the files/folders your Android App created. For your situation, use the [REST](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) api with DRIVE scope.

With the REST api, find the folder with id "root" and iterate (recursively) down the folder tree hierarchy collecting files. You may look at this [demo](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo), specifically the method '[testTree](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/MainActivity.java#L265)'

You CAN NOT use it DIRECTLY, since it does not use recursion to iterate down the hierarchy (my tree structure is pre-defined, your will be unknown).

So you have to:

- use REST flavor by setting '[USE_REST = true](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/MainActivity.java#L43)'
- re-write the 'testTree' method to use recursion. (hint: use MIME type "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" to identify folder as opposed to file)
- make sure you use 'DRIVE' scope, instead of 'DRIVE_FILE' [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdaademo/REST.java#L51).

**ANOTHER (higher performance) APPROACH:**

Since Google Drive is not a hierarchical structure by design (it only pretends to be), there is another possible approach to this problem (and you can test it in the [playground here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) - bottom of the page).

List all the files in the Drive in one shot (filter only fields you need) and decypher the tree structure from matching file/folder 'id' and 'parentIds'. Here is a typical result from a REST playground list:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?fields=items(id%2Cparents%2Fid)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

200 OK

{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "10JyzCXw7GcmEQPcxGHtlP4yAQ6tPXtK8nmrlVCThjL8",
   "parents": [
    {
     "id": "0B1mQUW2aFJfdbHlVQWdwOVhWMG8"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "0B1mQUW2aFJfdYWZTcmRMVWlReGc",
   "parents": [
    {
     "id": "0B1mQUW2aFJfdVlJYYVJxU3R1dFU"
    }
   ]
  },
```

This way, you need only one REST 'files().list()' call and 'String.equals()' to solve your problem. Assuming, the folders also have known MIME type, the logic should be quite easy.

Good Luck

Comment: it says:    `Error:No subject alternative DNS name matching services.gradle.org found.`

Comment: Sorry, the answer I gave was intended to send you in the proper direction (Google Drive problem), not as a gateway to solving other issues probably related to your IDE installation. I don't have any insight there.